# Convert some code from C# to VB.net throws error at compile time

Tags: c#, vb.net, events

I am trying to convert following code to VB.net

```
private void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var defaultTableData = new DefaultTableData();
        defaultTableData.CheckAndUpdate();

        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RSAConfigSwitch"].ToString().ToUpper() == "ON")
        {
            FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfigurationCreated += new EventHandler<ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs>(FederatedAuthentication_ServiceConfigurationCreated);

        }

    }

    void FederatedAuthentication_ServiceConfigurationCreated(object sender, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.Configuration.ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs e)
    {
        String certName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificateName"].ToString(); // read from web.config
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store store = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection col = store.Certificates.Find(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certName, true);
        var cookieProtectionCertificate = col[0];

        e.ServiceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers.AddOrReplace(
            new SessionSecurityTokenHandler(new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<CookieTransform>(
                new List<CookieTransform> 
                    { 
                        new DeflateCookieTransform(), 
                        new RsaEncryptionCookieTransform(cookieProtectionCertificate), 
                        new RsaSignatureCookieTransform(cookieProtectionCertificate) 
                    })
            ));
    }
```

Converted VB code

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
        ' Fires when the application is started 
        FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfigurationCreated += New EventHandler(Of ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs)(FederatedAuthentication_ServiceConfigurationCreated)





    End Sub
Private Sub FederatedAuthentication_ServiceConfigurationCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.Configuration.ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs)  

        Try 
            Dim appCertificateName As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("adfsCertName") 
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(appCertificateName) Then 
                Throw New Exception("ADFS_CERTIFICATE in config is empty") 
            End If 
            Dim store As X509Store = New X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine) 
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly) 
            Dim col As X509Certificate2Collection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, appCertificateName, True)

            Dim cookieProtectionCertificate As X509Certificate2 = col(0) 
           e.ServiceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers.AddOrReplace(New SessionSecurityTokenHandler(New System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of CookieTransform)(New List(Of CookieTransform)() With { _

        New DeflateCookieTransform(), _ 
        New RsaEncryptionCookieTransform(cookieProtectionCertificate), _ 
        New RsaSignatureCookieTransform(cookieProtectionCertificate) _ 
})))                                                                          


        Catch ex As Exception 
            Throw ex 
        End Try 
    End Sub
```

But I am getting following error
Error 103 'Public Shared Event ServiceConfigurationCreated(sender As Object, e As Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.Configuration.ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

Can somebody help me in converting the code?

Comment: Could you post the VB that you are trying to compile?

Comment: The error message already says it all. But since you didn’t post the converted VB code we can’t tell you which particular line to change. (Incidentally, this is bad C# code since it’s not thread safe.)

Comment: There are [free conversion tools](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) for you out there...

Comment: By the way, this *isn't* an exception. It's a compile-time error, which isn't the same thing.

Comment: Update the code and heading :)

Comment: @Ashwani K Have u tried http://www.developerfusion.com/ given link, from there, u just convert ur code and try once, it may will work.

Answer (score 0):

After converting your C# code to VB.net from http://www.developerfusion.com/ i got below codes from there.Just ty this.,

`Private Sub Application_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim defaultTableData = New DefaultTableData()
    defaultTableData.CheckAndUpdate()`

```
If ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("RSAConfigSwitch").ToString().ToUpper() = "ON" Then

    FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfigurationCreated += New EventHandler(Of ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs)(AddressOf FederatedAuthentication_ServiceConfigurationCreated)
End If
```

`End Sub`

`Private Sub FederatedAuthentication_ServiceConfigurationCreated(sender As Object, e As Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.Configuration.ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs)
    Dim certName As [String] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CertificateName").ToString()
    ' read from web.config
    Dim store As New System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
    store.Open(OpenFlags.[ReadOnly])
    Dim col As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection = store.Certificates.Find(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certName, True)
    Dim cookieProtectionCertificate = col(0)`

```
e.ServiceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers.AddOrReplace(New SessionSecurityTokenHandler(New System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of CookieTransform)(New List(Of CookieTransform)() From { _
    New DeflateCookieTransform(), _
    New RsaEncryptionCookieTransform(cookieProtectionCertificate), _
    New RsaSignatureCookieTransform(cookieProtectionCertificate) _
})))
```

`End Sub`

Hope this may helpful.,

Comment: I'm shocked that developerfusion uses the += syntax for adding event handlers in VB. That doesn't work. It needs to translate to AddHandler.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error tells you that there's something wrong with your event handler. VB doesn't support the += syntax for adding a handler. Use the AddHandler/AddressOf keywords instead:

```
   AddHandler  FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfigurationCreated, AddressOf FederatedAuthentication_ServiceConfigurationCreated
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things are off in your conversion - try this:

```
Private Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim defaultTableData = New DefaultTableData()
    defaultTableData.CheckAndUpdate()

    If ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("RSAConfigSwitch").ToString().ToUpper() = "ON" Then
        AddHandler FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfigurationCreated, AddressOf FederatedAuthentication_ServiceConfigurationCreated
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub FederatedAuthentication_ServiceConfigurationCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.Configuration.ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs)
    Dim certName As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CertificateName").ToString() ' read from web.config
    Dim store As New System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly)
    Dim col As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection = store.Certificates.Find(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certName, True)
    Dim cookieProtectionCertificate = col(0)

    e.ServiceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers.AddOrReplace(New SessionSecurityTokenHandler(New System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of CookieTransform)(New List(Of CookieTransform) From {
        New DeflateCookieTransform(),
        New RsaEncryptionCookieTransform(cookieProtectionCertificate),
        New RsaSignatureCookieTransform(cookieProtectionCertificate)
    })))
End Sub
```